# Beam CoGroupByKey with fixed window and event time based trigger generates random elements

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I have a pipeline in Beam that uses `CoGroupByKey` to combine 2 PCollections, first one reads from a Pub/Sub subscription and the second one uses the same PCollection, but enriches the data by looking up additional information from a table, using `JdbcIO.readAll`. So there is no way there would be data in the second PCollection without it being there in the first one.

There is a fixed window of 10seconds with an event based trigger like below;

```
Repeatedly.forever(
    AfterWatermark.pastEndOfWindow().withEarlyFirings(
        AfterProcessingTime.pastFirstElementInPane().plusDelayOf(Duration.standardSeconds(40))
    ).withLateFirings(AfterPane.elementCountAtLeast(1))
);
```

The issue I am seeing is that when I stop the pipeline using the `Drain` mode, it seems to be randomly generating elements for the second PCollection when there has not been any messages coming in to the input Pub/Sub topic. This also happens randomly when the pipeline is running as well, but not consistent, but when draining the pipeline I have been able to consistently reproduce this.

Please find the variation in input vs output below;

[image: CoGroupByKey step input vs output]

Comment: When the pipeline drains, it still processes the in-flight data. Are the "random elements" not in-flight data?

Comment: Hi @PeterKim, no they are not in-flight data, I have updated the question with a screenshot of the input vs out from the `CoGroupByKey` step, input from both collections have the same size, but the output is larger.

Comment: Can you check the watermark and pane.info to see if some of the elements are fired late due to the Trigger definition ? Also, it would be good to check the oldest ack message in pub/sub to see if the system was keeping up with the processing

Comment: Hi @JayadeepJayaraman, the screenshot was from an application was cancelled, so the watermark just states `Max watermark`. Regarding the unacked messages, we did have a backlog, but I would have assumed the input would also have had the same number right, since one of those PCollection is what pulls from Pub/Sub.

Comment: Have you used accumulatingFiredPanes or discardingFiredPanes?

Comment: Hello @RezaRokni, I am using `discardingFiredPanes` for the window.

Comment: I suggest you to file a public issue [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=491268) maybe the google support team could take a look in  your project to check the job logs and determine the root cause of the issue.

Comment: Hi @EnriqueZetina, ah OK will take a look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using a non-deterministic triggering, which means the output is sensitive to the exact ordering in which events come in. Another way to look at this is that CoGBK does not wait for both sides to come in; the trigger starts ticking as soon as either side comes in.

For example, lets call your PCollections A and A' respectively, and assume they each have two elements *a1*, *a2*, *a1'*, and *a2'* (of common provenance).

Suppose *a1* and *a1'* come into the CoGBK, 39 seconds passes, and then *a2* comes in (on the same key), another 2 seconds pass, then *a2'* comes in. The CoGBK will output ([*a1*, *a2*], [*a1'*]) when the 40-second mark hits, and then when the window closes ([], [*a2'*]) will get emitted. (Even if everything is on the same key, this could happen occasionally if there is more than a 40-second walltime delay going through the longer path, and will almost certainly happen for any late data (each side will fire separately).

Draining makes things worse, e.g. I think all processing time triggers fire immediately.

Comment: Hello, Thank you for the response, would changing the trigger to be based on event time vs processing time make it a deterministic trigger? I did try that as well, did not see any improvement. Please advise if there is a solution that would avoid this situation. If this is not directly related to this question, I can create a separate one.

Comment: If you use just `AfterWatermark.pastEndOfWindow()` (which is the default) you should not have these issues.

Comment: Hi @robertwb, Thank you. I did try that before, but it did not trigger any of the steps downstream of `CoGroupByKey`, I have removed `CoGroupByKey` and wrote a custom pardo that does the query and join in a single step, so I am not able to quickly test the old flow, will test and update here. I will mark this answer as accepted as it does explain the discrepancy in the elements processed.